# Can future company see a candidate who doing his own things outside of job and workhour as a threat?

Tags: job-search

As I am starting my own startup, I have some publications in Play Store (not very significant download yet). Employer also can find my website, although it's still an empty page.

I put publications as my portfolio section in my Resume.

What could be the possibilities from **future** employer's perspective? Can they see it as a threat?

Comment: "Can they see it as a threat?" - of course they can. But they probably won't unless the domain of your startup actually competes with your employer's domain - in which case this isn't a smart thing to do if you need your job.

Comment: @WorkerDrone Yes most workplaces have policies to prevent a employee to run a competing business without first getting approval from the company. Building software is okay so long as it isn't competing or using technologies from the workplace without authorization.

Comment: @All: Please see my edited post. It's for future employer, not my current..

Comment: As a potential future employer, your side work may be attractive if it is in the same vertical as their business. You may have expertise that they are specifically looking for. On the developer side, I see the drive and motivation to accomplish something in your field outside of work as very attractive as well. Self motivated developer? Yes please!

Comment: Having a few apps in the store is not going to hurt you. Might help you, in fact. Now if you are a big name in the tech industries, then it may or may not be a problem. Take for example if Bill Gates applied to Apple? Or Mark Zuckerberg applying to MySpace? Would they get the job ?

Answer (score 5):

Some employers will definitely not be happy with this and some will think that all good developers do such things.

The trick is to weed out companies that do not have a compatible culture with what you intend to do anyway, so go ahead and inform them and recognize that you will be weeding out employers you don't want to work for anyway.

I believe you are likely to find more compatible places in companies that are development shops as opposed to ones where development is a side effect of their main business. And large bureaucratic organizations may also (in my experience) be unlikely to want you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Read your employment contract and your employee hand book or HR policies. Most companies have policies that clearly states the rules about working "on the side", what is allowed and expected, and what approvals are needed and what circumstances.

It doesn't matter much if the company thinks it's a threat or not, what really matters is what your contract says and if, what you are doing, is in compliance or not.

As for the actual question: You company may or may not perceive this as a threat. That really depends on the specific circumstances. If your outside work is on a totally different field, that it's probably okay. If it's in the same field or even direct competition, it's a big no no.

Comment: Please see my edited post. It's for future employer, not my current..

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with a future employer - unless your app development is really significant to getting the positions, KEEP YOUR MOUTH SHUT.

If it comes up, ONLY discuss its popularity and features, and maybe the tools you used.  You should down-play how much time you're spending on developing and supporting it, and definitely down-play (or don't mention at all) any money you're getting from it.  These latter items really aren't things your employer has a right to know, and they can color the situation badly for you.  For example, if you're earning more than your salary from the app, your employer may rightfully be concerned that you'll jump ship if the app continues to do well.  If you're spending a lot of time on the app, the employer may be concerned that it will impact your performance on the job, and your availability for "company" concerns.

Be smart.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, some may see it as a threat, others see it as you having passion for your craft.  I believe the real question here is "what do I say to an employer if they are concerned about my side business/projects?"

In general, be honest, and be willing to explain how your side business/projects would affect your ability to perform for them as an employee.

I have my own company, and this had come up for me in an interview.  I was asked how much money the company was making and how many hours per week I dedicated to the company.

In my situation, I explained that the company was incorporated for legal protection for my side-projects, and that my full time employment always comes first.  They asked a few followup questions, and I answered honestly.  In the end, it wasn't a concern and was offered the position.